# How to reuse Grails application's domain classes?

Tags: grails

I have already create a Grails application. For some reasons I need to create another console application for someone to modify database data.

1. Is it possible to package Grails application as a JAR library, so that the console application can reuse those domain classes?
2. Or, I add/create some classes in Grails application and package it as a JAR and run as console application?

Answer (score 2):

If no better answer, probably I will use the [batch-launcher](http://www.grails.org/plugin/batch-launcher) plugin to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the domain classes in a JAR and tell Grails that these are your domain classes by adding a Hibernate XML file (in `grails-app/conf/hibernate`) that refers to the classes in this JAR. You can use this JAR in any other Java/Groovy application, but obviously they'll only have the persistence methods (dynamic finders, `save()`, etc.) when used in a Grails app.

Comment: You also wouldn't get any functionality that is inside a service or a controller. All you get is what's in the domain classes.